# why does running nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade gives symlink error after switching to unstable channel?

Tags: linux, package-management, symlink, nixos, nix

Nevermind, i fixed it, by manually running `nix-channel update` before running `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade`

I am trying to upgrade from nix-23.05 to unstable but I'm getting some weird errors.

Heres how I switched:

- I ran "`sudo nix-channel --add https://channels.nixos.org/nixos-unstable nixos`"
- I ran "`sudo nix-channel --add https://channels.nixos.org/nixpkgs-unstable nixpkgs`"

output of `sudo nix-channel --list` is:

```
nixos https://channels.nixos.org/nixos-unstable
nixpkgs https://channels.nixos.org/nixpkgs-unstable
```

running `sudo nixos-rebuid switch` works just fine, but heres the output i get from `sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade`:

`error: reading symbolic link '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixpkgs': No such file or directory`

I can't find anything online about this problem, thanks if you solve it.